# Testing if a Variable Contains a Function in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am writing a common lisp program and I have a variable that can contain either a string or a function. I want to call the function if it is one and return that as well as the string. How do I test if a variable is a function?

Code so far:

```
(defun string-or-function (var)
 (if (typep var 'simple-array)
   var
   (if "Function equivalent of typep goes here."


(setf temp (fn-that-does-something))
(string-or-function temp)
```

Edit: Code that works:

```
(defun string-or-function (var)
 (let ((s-or-f (type-of var)))
  (if (equal s-or-f 'function)
   (print "function")
    (if (equal (car s-or-f) 'simple-array)
     (print "string")))))
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common Lisp has a predicative type system. The notion that a value has a "principal" type doesn't make as much sense in Lisp. The `type-of` function is actually fairly infrequently used, as it makes less sense to ask "What is the type of X" and more sense to ask "Is X of type Y". This can be done with `typep`, or in your case more concisely with `typecase`, which is just a case statement for types.

```
(defun string-or-function (var)
    (typecase var
      (string (format t "string"))
      (function (format t "function"))
      (t (format t "something else"))))
```

Comment: Thanks that is very concise.

Comment: "more concisely with typecase": I really like typecase, but `(typep var '(or string function))` is shorter ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to call the function if it is one and return that as well as the string.

I think you mean something like this:

```
(defun evaluate (arg)
  "Returns something from evaluating ARG in some manner.  If ARG is a string,
return it.  If ARG is a function, call it with no arguments and return its
return value(s)."
  (ctypecase arg
    (string arg)
    (function (funcall arg))))
```

If you need extensibility:

```
(defgeneric evaluate (arg)
  (:documentation "Returns something from evaluating ARG in some manner."))

(defmethod evaluate ((arg string))
  arg)

(defmethod evaluate ((arg function))
  (funcall arg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other ways:

```
(defun string-or-function-p (x)
  (typep x '(or string function)))
```

...but you can probably also use check-type, which is not a predicate but a check which signals a restartable condition in case the value does not satisfy the type specification:

```
(check-type place (or string function))
```

If you happen to use this type a lot, define a custom type:

```
(deftype string-or-fun () '(or string function))
```

Of course, you can also use generic functions depending on your needs (silly example):

```
(defgeneric execute (object)
  (:method ((s string)) (eval (read-from-string s)))
  (:method ((f function)) (funcall f)))
```

But note that generic function dispatch on *classes*, not *types*, which are different things.

Answer (score -1):

```
(eq (type-of var) 'function)
```

However, remember that Common Lisp keeps variables and function names in different namespaces, so (var 1 2 3) and (cons var 1) are looking in two different places. You probably cannot call var like (var), but will rather need to use (funcall var), depending on which namespace this is in.

Basically, you probably shouldn't be stuffing a function-or-maybe-a-string into one variable.

Comment: `(type-of #'car)` is `compiled-function` on my GNU CLisp. Since it's a subclass of `function`, your expression will incorrectly state that it is not a function.

Comment: And on top of that, there's already [**functionp**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fnp.htm) that would work in both cases.